# Do I need a google maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently working on a school project where I have to create a website, I have created a feature where google maps can be used as a route planner.

The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/maps" target="RoutePlanner">
  <input name="saddr" type="text" id="saddr">
  <input name="output" type="hidden" value="embed">
  <input name="daddr" type="text" id="daddr">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br>
<iframe name="RoutePlanner" width="425" height="350" src="https://www.google.com/maps?z=5&amp;f=d&amp;output=embed&amp;ll=52.355518,-1.174320">
    </iframe>
```

As you can see it is very simple but works for the purpose I need it, however my teacher suggests that when I use this file to connect to a server to use on my website, it may have to use an API, why is this and how would I accomplish this?

Thanks, Henry

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API lets you customize maps with your own content and imagery for display on web pages and to use the Maps JavaScript API, you must register your app project on the Google Cloud Platform Console and get a Google API key which you can add to your app. For this purpose of displaying a simple map you can use google maps free version.

Go to this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key and create a new project and billing account. After creating a API key you can close your billing account and it will not charge any fee.

Place your API key in HTML file

```
 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Please refer the Google Map API documentation for further reference. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/

Comment: Thanks, I setup an API key last night, I'll add it to the file now, thanks.

Comment: I will, just need my teacher to setup the server so I can have a website to use it on, not a local file.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.